# Searching a Data.Table in R

Tags: r, search, dataframe, data.table

I'm having a bit of an issue searching a data table in R (I'm relatively new to the data.table package and R in general so my issue may be trivial, but I can't seem to find anything online).

Anyway, I have a column of time values and a column of millisecond values for their respective time in a data table, and I have a second set of information in a different data table (specifically another time value and another millisecond value) and I want to able to use this second set of information to find the closest time and millisecond values in the data table such that it is less than or equal to the time and millisecond values I have.

For example, let's say I have the following code:

```
# DATA TABLE of time and millisecond values

Timevec <- c("10:00:05", "10:00:45", "10:01:03", "10:01:27", "10:01:52", "10:02:07", "10:02:13", "10:02:29", "10:02:33", "10:02:40", "10:02:44")
MilliSecond <- c(5, 321, 786, 79, 930, 680, 753, 214, 964, 832, 135)
tdf <- data.frame(Timevec, MilliSecond,(stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
setDT(tdf)

# Individual time and millisecond values

timesingle <- c("10:02:07")
millisecondsingle <- c(656)
sdf <- data.frame(timesingle ,millisecondsingle,(stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
setDT(sdf)
```

In this case, since the time is 10:02:07 and milliseconds is 656, the closest time in the first data table (which is also less than or equal to the time I have) would be at 10:01:52 with its milliseconds at 930

I'm trying to find a way to perform this operation but I'm not sure how. I originally had the following code to try and do this for me:

```
max(which(tdf$Timevec<=sdf[1,time1] & tdf$MilliSecond <= sdf[1,milli1]))
```

I originally hoped this would give me the index of the relevent time and millisecond columns I was after, but this failed since it only seemed to look at either one or the other condition. Does anyone know a better function or method to implement this? I don't mind if it's some sort of weird loop or anything, I'm just really not sure what to do for this so I'd appreciate any help I can get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of a strange way to store times, and a strange way to construct the data table. You should avoid labeling a column as a vector also

```
Timevec <- c("10:00:05", "10:00:45", "10:01:03", "10:01:27", "10:01:52", "10:02:07", "10:02:13", "10:02:29", "10:02:33", "10:02:40", "10:02:44")
MilliSecond <- c(5, 321, 786, 79, 930, 680, 753, 214, 964, 832, 135)
tdf <- data.table("time" = Timevec, "ms" = MilliSecond)
```

let just use lubridate and add milliseconds

```
 library(lubridate)
    > print(betterTime <- (hms(tdf$Timevec) + tdf$MilliSecond / 1000))
 [1] "10H 0M 5.005S"  "10H 0M 45.321S" "10H 1M 3.786S"  "10H 1M 27.079S" "10H 1M 52.93S"  "10H 2M 7.68S"   "10H 2M 13.753S" "10H 2M 29.214S" "10H 2M 33.964S" "10H 2M 40.832S" "10H 2M 44.135S"
```

Thats just to see how it works. But you can actually do the conversion in-table!

```
otherrandomtime <- "10:02:13"
otherrandomms <- 751 # note that this demonstrates that milliseconds can break the tie.
print(otherConverted <- hms(otherrandomtime) + otherrandomms / 1000)
[1] "10H 2M 13.751S"

tail(tdf[(hms(time) + ms/1000) < hms(otherrandomtime) + otherrandomms / 1000],1)
       time  ms
1: 10:02:07 680
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply, I had quite a busy day. This is exactly what I was looking for and it's extremely easy to understand, thanks heaps! I would like to vote you up as well but my account is new so I'm not able to do so unfortunately :/